# How to restrict another class to alter the properties in java

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

According to Encapsulation fields should be private and public getter-setters.

But using setter there is a way that another class can alter the value of private field, So what should be the way to protect fields.

Please consider this class for discussion :

```
    class Emp {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Emp() {}

    // getters and setters

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make the class immutable.

> An immutable object is one that will not change state after it is
>   instantiated.

```
final class Emp {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Emp(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

Making the class final ensures this class can not be subclassed. This subclass could potentially add mutability.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want other classes to be able to change a field via a setter, simply don't provide the setter.   Declaring the setter as `private` has the same effect.

You said:

> According to Encapsulation fields should be private and public getter-setters.

Actually, the key requirement for achieving encapsulation is to declare the fields as `private`.   That is what prevents other classes from "seeing" or depending on how the property is implemented.  Providing getters and/or setters is *optional*.

Answer (score 0):

When you need the setters add some kind of control:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

When you use java beans it is also possible to use roles:

```
@RolesAllowed("Administrator")
public void setName(String nam) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass data in constructors:

```
   class Emp {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Emp(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }

    // getters

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```